# SemanticException [Error 10128]: Not yet supported place for UDAF 'sum' in Hive/Hue

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, hiveql, hue

From this sentence:

```
SELECT a.comunity, sum(b.cont_woman),sum(b.cont_men)

FROM cont_per_comunity.states_per_comunities a

JOIN cont_per_comunity.cont_per_state b

ON a.state = b.state

WHERE sum(b.cont_woman) >= sum(b.cont_men)

GROUP BY a.comunity;
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Error occurred executing hive query: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 9:6 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'sum'
> ```

Is there another way to select the sum of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do that in a `having` clause, or in an outer query.  You can't use aggregate functions in a where clause like you are trying to do.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.comunity, sum(b.cont_woman),sum(b.cont_men)
FROM cont_per_comunity.states_per_comunities a
JOIN cont_per_comunity.cont_per_state b
ON a.state = b.state
GROUP BY a.comunity
having sum(b.cont_woman) >= sum(b.cont_men)
```

Or

```
select * from (
    SELECT a.comunity, sum(b.cont_woman) as cont_woman
    ,sum(b.cont_men) as cont_men
    FROM cont_per_comunity.states_per_comunities a
    JOIN cont_per_comunity.cont_per_state b
    ON a.state = b.state
    GROUP BY a.comunity ) t
    where cont_woman >= cont_men
```